# Integration in client MVC Owin by identity server .net core 7

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, jwt, openid-connect, identity-server

I have client app on target EntityFramework 4.8

config identity server is:

```
builder.Services.AddOpenIddict()

    .AddCore(options =>
    {
        options.UseEntityFrameworkCore()
               .UseDbContext<IdentityServerDbContext>();
    })
    .AddServer(options =>
    {

        options.SetAccessTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
        options.SetTokenEndpointUris("connect/token")
        .SetLogoutEndpointUris("connect/logout")
        .SetAuthorizationEndpointUris("connect/authorize");

        options.AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow();

        options.AddEncryptionKey(new SymmetricSecurityKey(
          Convert.FromBase64String("YYYYYYYYYY=")));

        options.AddDevelopmentEncryptionCertificate()
               .AddDevelopmentSigningCertificate();

        options.UseAspNetCore()
        .EnableAuthorizationEndpointPassthrough()
        .EnableLogoutEndpointPassthrough()
        .EnableTokenEndpointPassthrough();

        options.AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow()
                .AllowRefreshTokenFlow();
    })
    .AddValidation(options =>
    {
        options.UseLocalServer();
        options.UseAspNetCore();
    });

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(c =>
    {
        c.LoginPath = "/Authenticate";
    });
```

and config client app .nbet core 7 is:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);



builder.Services.AddOpenIddict()
    .AddValidation(options =>
    {
        options.SetIssuer("https://localhost:7000/");
        options.AddAudiences("resource_server_1");    
        options.AddEncryptionKey(new SymmetricSecurityKey(
            Convert.FromBase64String("YYYYYYYYYY=")));

        options.UseSystemNetHttp();

        options.UseAspNetCore();
    });
```

and config client app .net framework 4.8 is

```
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
var tokenParameter = new TokenValidationParameters();
tokenParameter.IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
Convert.FromBase64String("YYYYYYYYYY="));
  var oidcOptions = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
  {
      Authority = "https://localhost:7000",
      ClientId = "milad-develop",
      ClientSecret = "xx",
      PostLogoutRedirectUri = "http://localhost:2020/account/logout",
      RedirectUri = "http://localhost:2020/account/callback",
      ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code,
      Scope = "api1"
  }
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(oidcOptions);
```

Now
I have no problem with .net core programs, but my .net framework program always shows the token generated from the identity server as invalid and gives a 401 error.